# Does managed property play any role while crawl component crawls the content source in sharepoint 2010 enterprise search?

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise

As per my knowledge,When crawl component crawls content source it prepares index partition and moves to query component.The query component takes request from user and with the help of property db gives search result to user.

So my question: does crawl component take help from managed property while crawling the content source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crawl component needs the managed properties in order to know how it should store the value of the crawled properties.

If there is no managed property matching a crawled property then it isn't stored.

Comment: Thanks.So overall my understanding:Crawl component checks mamaged property for crawling content sources.Also Index which it creates is based on managed property.Is it right?

Comment: The Crawler/indexer gets crawled properties from the Content Sources and IFilters, it then checks the manages properties for how to store these values in the property database. The index itself is for full text and don't depend on manages properties

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving such a wonderful understanding related to crawling.